# Installing Piklab

Tags: installation, package-management, compiling

I have tried to install Piklab into my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32-bit, and I tried to use [this](http://photonics.engr.uga.edu/piklab/index.html) and [this](http://resumiendooo.blogspot.com.br/2012/08/compilar-piklab-en-ubuntu-1204.html) method. None of them really worked.
During `cmake .`, my shell displays me lots of messages, but I think this is the main one:

```
-- Could NOT find ncurses (missing NCURSES_LIBRARY NCURSES_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

What can I do to solve this situation? I've tried to install the most recent version, got from SourceForge.

Comment: You can upload *all* the output in paste.ubuntu.com and then link it into your question. About your line, you have to install the `ncurses` library, to do so enter in terminal: `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev`

Comment: It worked perfectly! Kind of a silly detail that I wasn't thinking about it. Thanks @Lucio :)

Comment: If you don't care I will transfer my comment into an answer, where you can [mark as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/1141/62483) and upvote it. So future users will know how to solve the problem.

Comment: Sure, no problem at all! You helped me, so I think you deserve the credits ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, the main information is that line. It is telling you that your system doesn't have the `ncurses` library.

To install it you have to enter the next command in a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

You get that error message because you haven't installed a dependency, which compiling this software requires.

[Their wiki mentions](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/piklab/index.php?title=Compilation_for_Linux) these dependencies that you need to have installed:

```
libusb-dev libreadline-dev libqt4-dev kdelibs5-dev
```

You can install them through running `sudo apt-get install [package names]` in the terminal.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not the case. I've downloaded several packages from both links that I tagged before, including those ones that you recommended me... the same message keeps coming back.

Maybe this information is important: I'm running my Ubuntu over VMWare Player.

Comment: Did you every try to install `ncurses` through `sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev` as Lucio suggested?

Comment: It worked perfectly! Kind of a silly detail that I wasn't thinking about it. Thanks @daniel :)